# Drawing a graph in latex?

Tags: pgfplots

I need help with this code 
It is my first time using latex

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{minipage}[r]{0.49\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\begin{axis}[grid=magor,
grid style={smooth},
xmin=0,xmax=3,
xlabel=$t$,
ylabel={$x(t),y(t)$},
variable=t]
\addplot[blue,line width=1,smooth]plot
[domain=0:3.5,samples=350]expression{(1+2t)exp(-2t)\sin(200t 3.14)};
\addplot[red,line width=1,smooth,style={dashed}]plot
[domain=0:3.5,samples=150]expression{(1+2t)exp(-2t)};
\addplot[red,line width=1,smooth,style={dashed}]plot
[domain=0:3.5,samples=150]expression{-(1+2t)exp(-2t)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Damping sinusne funkcije}
\label{damping}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please enter the code (as formatted text)  and formulate a specific question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how your code should look

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
    axis lines = middle,
    grid = major,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=3, 
]
\addplot[smooth,blue,domain=0:3.5, variable=\t] 
({\t},{(1+2*\t)*exp(2*\t)*sin(280*pi*t)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Here are main parts of writing code for the plot. For centering your window you use `\begin{center}`.